# SQLite error column (that exists) does not exist when compiling CREATE VIEW

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to create a view but for some reason it's giving me a column does not exist error. This isn't the first view I've made and all the others are working, the tables are there, columns and all ( I checked with DBBrowser and everything but this one VIEW is not working ).

I've checked my whitespaces, it's all in order but something is going wrong and I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure out what. Can someone shed some light on this?

**LogCat**

```
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jc.pseudocc/com.example.jc.pseudocc.AccountManager}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Companies.CompanyID (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE VIEW ViewCompanies AS SELECT Companies.CompanyID AS _id, Payments.GroupID, Payments.PaymentDue, Payments.DateDue FROM Payments JOIN Accounts ON Payments.GroupID = Accounts.AccountID
```

**Tables**

COMPANY

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + COMPANY + " (" + colCompID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            colCompClass + " TEXT)");
```

PAYMENTS

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + PAYMENTS + " (" + colPayID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , " +
            colGroupID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            colPayBal + " TEXT, " +
            colInterest + " TEXT, " +
            colPayDue + " TEXT, " +
            colDateDue + " TEXT, " +
            colPayDate + " TEXT, " +
            "FOREIGN KEY (" + colGroupID + ") REFERENCES " + ACCOUNTS + " (" + colID + ") ON DELETE CASCADE);");
```

**VIEW**

```
db.execSQL("CREATE VIEW " + viewComps +
            " AS SELECT " + COMPANY + "." + colCompID + " AS _id," +
            " " + COMPANY + "." + colCompClass + "," +
            " " + PAYMENTS + "." + colGroupID + "," +
            " " + PAYMENTS + "." + colPayDue + "," +
            " " + PAYMENTS + "." + colDateDue + "" +
            " FROM " + PAYMENTS +
            " JOIN " + ACCOUNTS + " ON " + PAYMENTS + "." + colGroupID + " = " + ACCOUNTS + "." + colID );
```

Comment: should `" FROM " + PAYMENTS +` be `" FROM " + PAYMENTS + ", " + COMPANY +` ?

Comment: I'm crying right now, that tears it I'm not coding when subbing monster for sleep anymore. Thank you for that, I had a feeling I was just missing something. Post it as an answer so we can complete my first stupid question in SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating your view, you reference COMPANY and PAYMENTS. You need to indicate that in the `FROM` section of your query:

replace

```
" FROM " + PAYMENTS +
```

with

```
" FROM " + PAYMENTS + ", " + COMPANY +
```